# Make my screen dimmer than the lowest setting available on my Moto Droid?

Tags: settings, screen-brightness

I primarily use my phone at night and any screen that is white is super bright, even when the brightness is turned as low as it can go (0%).  Dolphin HD has an add-on called [Dolphin Brightness](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dolphin-brightness/mobi.mgeek.brightness) that actually turns the screen's brightness down lower than the 0% setting in the Settings menu.  Unfortunately, as soon as I leave Dolphin HD, it goes back to the stock brightness level.  Is there anyway to dial the brightness level down like the add-on, but for every app and the home screen?

I have tried several apps that give you access to brightness control, like Quick Settings but they simply give you the same level options that the stock settings menu gives you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this post on the [droidforums.net](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/adamz/31561-sg-6-0-1-low-brightness-hack-issue.html) that has a custom app to manage brightness. Requires root though.

Comment: That worked exactly how I needed it to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I use [Dimmer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dimmer-%28-night-mode-%29/com.geekyouup.android.dimmer) which gives me a slightly lower level of brightness than the stock settings ;)

Comment: Thanks but this didn't make my screen any dimmer than the stock settings allowed.

Answer (score 3):

While I prefer the app kchau suggested because of it's simplicity, this one works as well: [adjBrightness](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adjbrightness/com.deskangel.adjbrightness)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that works well and doesn't require a rooted device: [**Screen Filter**](http://www.appbrain.com/app/screen-filter/com.haxor)