# Is there a TRUE brightness controlling app?

Tags: battery, screen-brightness

I need to set my brightness below what Android allows me, and thus I'm testing a bunch of "dimming" apps. What they all have in common though is that they put on a filter over other apps so while they protect your eyes they do nothing to get you more battery life.

Is there an app that has low-level access to the screen brightness so that when you go beyond the default minimum brightness it actually gets you more battery life?

RootDim might be fitting, but I need something without root access.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the brightness levels are coded into the kernel. If I'm correct, then no app can really override them if you want to go lower than the minimum - you'd need to flash a custom kernel that has more flexible brightness ranges.

Comment: Related: [How can I reduce screen brightness below the minimum without an app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44270)

Comment: Related: [Make my screen dimmer than the lowest setting available on my Moto Droid?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2063)

Comment: Thanks @Krampus, looks like I was wrong. Won't be the last time.

Comment: @user1891836: Don't know if this might help, but can you try [DroidSet Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.ckd.droidsetfree&hl=en). The app has an auto brightness and manual brightness function much like Android screen brightness setting.

Comment: Having tested Lux thoroughly I can confirm it only adds a layer of grey (or brown, if in its "night mode", or red, if in its "astronomer" moder). Lux's blurb talks about altering the quality of the backlight, but this is not true. It only alters how much you can SEE of the backlit screen by obscuring it with a layer of grey (or brown, or red). "DroidSet Free" is more limited than "Lux" and simply offers a single brightness-control slider that is much like the one that comes with the Android systems.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [Lux Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vitocassisi.luxlite) and it works well for me.

> Lux isn't your ordinary brightness app. It intelligently adjusts the brightness of your display based on the environment you're in. If you step into a dimly lit room, Lux will automatically lower the brightness of your display to make it not only comfortable to read, but to also preserve battery power.
>
> Lux is also able to adjust the screen temperature of your display automatically to make it appropriate for night usage. At sunset, you can have Lux automatically warm your display and switch to your Night profile. If you're an astronomer, you can enable astronomer mode to cut out harsh white light. If you have a root enabled phone, you may even be able to apply these enhancements at a low level with Lux's plug-in system.
>
> Perhaps the best thing about Lux is that you can teach it how to behave. If the backlight is too bright or dim for your liking, simply open the provided Dashboard, adjust the brightness slider to the level you desire, then hold the link button. Lux will use this new 'link' as a reference in future.

Comment: Are you sure *Lux Lite* is not only applying filters as well? The app's feature description (following your quote) makes me assume so, especially *Astronomer mode. Adds a red filter to your display to preserve the eyesight of stargazers.* The others could be interpreted both ways; no clear hint. On the other hand, [Screen Adjuster](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Screen-Adjuster/com.netmanslab.sa) explicitly mentions *dimming the screen 15-100% (below minimum system brightness)* and *system brightness 0-100% adjustment* (note: not filter).

Comment: Astronomer mode is an extra filter over and above the backlight dimming options. (Gives the screen a red cast.)

Comment: I thought so, yes – but from the app's description it's not clear. Can you confirm everything else is really reducing brightness (and thus power-saving, as requested by the OP), and not just other filters?

Comment: According to Battery Doctor, Lux Lite is draining battery like crazy so it is certainly not controlling system brightness

Comment: @user1891836: Doesn't drain my battery.